# Passing properties to this in cleaner way

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there another clean way to write this code so that the properties from data array are passed directly to this object.

```
        this.Email = data[0].Email;
        this.RealName = data[0].RealName;
        this.JobTitle = data[0].JobTitle;
        this.UserDID = data[0].UserDID;
        this.CreatedDateTime = data[0].CreatedDateTime;
        this.ApplicationCount = data[0].ApplicationCount;
        this.CountApply = data[0].CountApply;
        this.CountResume = data[0].CountResume;
        this.LastEmailAction = data[0].LastEmailAction;
        this.CountEmailActions = data[0].CountEmailActions;
        this.LastResume = data[0].LastResume;
        this.LastApply = data[0].LastApply;
```

Comment: create an array of keys and loop through array and add these properties on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all the properties from `data[0]` assigned to the object pointed to by `this`, you can use `Object.assign()` which will copy all enumerable properties from the source object to the target object:

```
Object.assign(this, data[0]);
```

If you want only select properties, then you can make a list of those properties and loop through them:

```
['Email', 'RealName', ...].forEach(prop => {this[prop] = data[0][prop]});
```